Question about weak derivative of a function
Consider that $w\in W^{1,p}((0,1))$ with $w(x)>0$ for a.a. $x\in (0,1)$. Here $p>1$ is a constant exponent.
Is it necesarily true that $\dfrac{w'}{w}\in L^1(\Omega)$?
My attempt to prove this is by considering the function $\ln(w)$ and trying to show that the weak derivative of $\ln(w)$ is $\dfrac{w'}{w}$. But I get stucked... I have identified here $w$ a.e. with an absolute continuous function, so its derivative exists a.e. in the classical sense.
If it is true in one dimension, can it be generalized to $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ - a bounded domain?
So if $w\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $w(x)>0$ for a.a. $x\in\Omega$ then is it true that: $\dfrac{1}{w}\cdot\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x_i}\in L^1(\Omega)$ for any $i\in\overline{1,N}$.
Here we may identify $w$ with an absolute continuous function on any segment with a cardinal direction.
Another attempt was to consider the function $w_{\epsilon}(x)=\begin{cases} \epsilon, w(x)\leq \epsilon\\ w(x), w(x)\in \left (\epsilon, \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \right )\\ \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}, w(x)\geq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\end{cases}$. We have that $w_{\epsilon}\to w$ pointwise, and $w_\epsilon\in W^{1,p}\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

No. Take $w(x) = x$.
$$
%..........................
$$
